# iam a newbie in coding why the number o wrongs always displaying 5

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot
print(" Welcome to type tester")
words = ["running","kangroo","girrafe","banana","donkey"]
word = random.choice(words)
typed = 0
wrong = 0
while typed < 5:
    word_typed = input("type the word : "+word+". then press enter : ").lower
    typed += 1
    if word_typed != word:
        wrong += 1
        continue
    else:
        continue
print(wrong)
```

its always printing 5 when typed correct also.
dont mind the time module and matplotlib i want them in further of this project
pls help me to solve this

Comment: `else` should `break`, not `continue` the loop. You `continue` five times, no matter what the `input` was.

Comment: i want to run it for five times and record the times that the word is typed wrong

Comment: Change `.lower` to `.lower()`.  With out the parentheses, you aren't calling the method, but are instead returning the method (rather than a string).

Comment: The `continue` statements can simply be removed (as can the `else`), since the loop will continue if you just fall through.  It will still execute 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in where you declare `word_typed`. You should use `.lower()`, (with the empty parentheses), instead of just `.lower` (without parentheses). The reason is because you need to call the `.lower` method to return the string in lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a nice little piece of code to get familiar with Python. There are a few key things here that you should take note of:

- There are two main keywords you'll see in python with looping: **break** and **continue**. Break acts as a sort of gateway out of your loop. Once you call it, you will jump to the line after at the end of your loop. Continue, however, does something a bit different. The continue keyword will actually take you back up to the *top* of your loop. So, in your example, if the user enters a wrong word, the variable called "wrong" gets incremented, and the continue keyword takes the program back to the top. You might now see the issue with when the user enters the *correct* word. You are once again calling the continue statement! This will take us back up to the top, thus guaranteeing that this loop will iterate exactly 5 times.
- Lastly, without going too much into detail, your `.lower()` method should have a pair of parenthesis at the end (similar to how I typed it above). You are actually assigning your word_typed to be the memory address of the method itself! A good way to visualize this is to print out your word_typed variable in the while loop. You'll notice that you print out a bizarre line of text (certainly not the text you typed into the console).

Therefore, the line in question is directly after your else statement within the while loop. Hopefully you now see why you should be using a break statement there instead of a continue statement, as well as using the method call `.lower()` in the syntactically appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

print(" Welcome to type tester")
words = ["running", "kangroo", "girrafe", "banana", "donkey"]
typed = 0
wrong = 0
while typed < 5:
    # Put random in the body of the loop
    word = random.choice(words)
    word_typed = input("type the word : " + word + ". then press enter : ").lower()
    typed += 1
    if word_typed != word:
        wrong += 1
print(wrong)
```